# Azure web app browser based access restriction

Tags: browser, azure-web-app-service, cross-browser

I am hosting an angular application in azure web app. I want my application should be only accessible on chrome browser. If someone access the site from other browser then user should redirect to browser restriction page. So to achieve this is there any policy available that can be added to web app, instead of writting the code to detect the browser and then redirect?

- Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Azure web app does not have the functionality to restrict access to the browser as you described.**

***Reason***

1. Azure app service (Windows & Linux) is essentially a webserver running in a sandbox, which is no different from real IIS or Nginx and Apache.
2. WebServer provides program deployment and access functions, and only receives `HttpRequest`. As for the information contained in `HttpRequest`, azure app service does not provide `analysis`.

   For example, adding `User-Agent: Chrome` is the specific information contained in HttpRequest. This means that we can only determine the source by parsing the HttpRequest through the code.